# I facing issue while configuring bitbucket ssh key to jenkins server for ci?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

I am facing issue while configuring SSH Key to jenkins for Bitbucket to Jenkins CI. I created SSH key using this CMD inside of .ssh directory `ssh-keygen` I copied private key and pasted to jenkins credentials side using SSH Key, Then public key I copied and pasted to bitbucket SSH key side. then I its showing this Error `stderr: No RSA host key is known for bitbucket.org and you have requested strict checking.`

Reference Image:

[image: Error Message from Jenkins Server]

I need to connect bitbucket to jenkins and build the private repo code using SSH Key.

Comment: If anyone know about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When using the bitbucket plugin, you have to use Oauth connection for the top level connection. Then you can use an ssh key in the filter section.

- Go to https://bitbucket.org//workspace/settings/api
- Add Consumer like [image]
- Grab key and secret
- Add credentials as username & password (I believe)
- Now go back into pipeline configuration using that credential
- You should be able to put in the workspace, and the repos will show up in the filter

That will fix the issue, if you want to checkout over ssh, ensure you have the bitbucket branch source plugin installed. If you have it, you should see an option of `checkout over ssh`
[image]

If you are using Jenkins template engine and you want to add a library, you would use the format you have in the picture already.